# Scraping Tripadvisor Reviews, Location

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from TripAdvisor for Top 30 Restaurants. I was able to get the list of these restaurants. Further, I am able to scrape data for review title and date successfully. I am using BeautifulSoup and Requests to get this data. However, following are the problem areas:

## While scraping reviews, firstly not able to get full length of reviews and secondly at some places there are replies from the owner which share the same tag and class as the review and thus are getting scraped as well. I want to exclude these replies

### Parse Link

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs


link='https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Restaurant_Review-g294265-d1193730-Reviews-Entre_Nous_creperie-Singapore.html'
openlink=requests.get(link)
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(openlink.text,'lxml')
```

### Reviewer Name

```
rnamedata=soup.find_all('span',class_='expand_inline scrname')
rnames=[]
i=0
for i in range(len(rnamedata)):
rnames.append(rnamedata[i].text)
rnames[i]=rnames[i].replace("\n","")
```

**Length of list comes out to be 10**

### Review Text

```
rdetaildata=soup.find_all('p',class_='partial_entry')
rdetails=[]
i=0
for i in range(len(rdetaildata)):
rdetails.append(rdetaildata[i].text)
rdetails[i]=rdetails[i].replace("\n","")
```

**Length of list comes out to be 20 because of replies from owners. I want to exclude these owner replies. Also, this only gives partial review**

## Location of the reviewer is not available for all users, which is fine, but how do I scrape in such a way that i can input "NA" against those who have not mentioned their location. Because of this, I am not able to map location against reviews

### Review Location

```
rlocdata=soup.find_all('span',class_='expand_inline userLocation')
rlocs=[]
i=0
for i in range(len(rlocdata)):
rlocs.append(rlocdata[i].text)
rlocs[i]=rlocs[i].replace("\n","")
```

**Length of the list comes out to be 9 as one reviewer has not mentioned location. I would want length to be 10 with one entry as NA for which data is not available.**

## Reviewer contribution and helpful votes also share the same tag and class so how do i segregate them into their respective categories.

### Review Contributions

```
rcontridata=soup.find_all('span',class_='badgetext')
rcontri=[]
i=0
for i in range(len(rcontri)):
rcontri.append(rcontridata[i].text)
rcontri[i]=rcontri[i].replace("\n","")
```

**Again, this gives a list of length 18 because it returns both contribution and helpful votes data as they share same tag and class. I want them in different objects**

**Thanks for all your help Guys!**

Comment: Is it a question or exibition of code? Try minimal code with enough explanation as to what you wanna get assistance for. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM: I have edited the question and have only shown relevant codes; hopefully, it is better now.